# Css paragraphs jump over

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

i have some small css issue. I am using bootstrap for my website, but some grid paragraphs are not displayed as i expect.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
<h4>{BTITLE}</h4>
<p><img src="/images/bookies/{BIMG}.gif" class="img-thumbnail" style="float:left; margin: 5px;">{BSHORT}</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-success" href="{BLINK}" role="button" target="_blank">View {BIMG} bonus &raquo;</a></p>
```

This is the html code for each paragraph. And here is how it looks like some times. I have made some test and when the size of the text / title is too long it looks terrible, otherwise is ok.

[image]

What should i change in order to look better ?

Comment: `float`ing elements can cause elements after to "flow up" underneath (as `float`ing elements gives them no height AFAIK). Could you try inserting `<i class="clearfix"></i>` just after the last `</p>` (before the closing `</div>` tag) of each tile? This will `clear` any effect of the previous `float` (i.e. the one you're using to display the thumbnail). Let me know if you have any luck

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You should define 'look better' in more detail. We cannot read your mind in how you want your website designed. The thing that I would improve is: the vertical aligning of the buttons and divs (one way to achieve this would be by giving them somekind of simular height)

Comment: @RMo - I agree with your comment about defining "look better". What I get from the OP is that the rows should line up neatly - and not float up into one another

Comment: I think you should look into "Responsive Column Resets" for Bootstrap. You can then apply the `clearfix` class only when necessary: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Better still, you could also look into using `flex` to display your columns/rows/tiles :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to align all the 6 blocks in a certain way. 3 on 1st row and the next 3 columns on the second row.

Make 2 separate rows so that your 1st three columns are independent from the next three rows. And 2nd option is: you can to set a min height of the row. The min-height has to be equal to the maximum content of a particular column. But I prefer it having the content in two separate sections.

Example code below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div>
</div>
```

It's good to have a single column on XS view port for which the code below:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. Good suggestion, and I can see how this will work for 3 columns. But the OP also has 2 columns on an `xs` viewport, so this unfortunately won't solve the OP's issue completely

Comment: For an xs view port, rather than cramping by showing 2 columns in each row you can show all the columns one below the other. This helps readability as well.  <div class="col-lg-4">..</div> can be replaced by <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">..</div>

Comment: That's a question you'd need to ask @Vince. Only issue I see is if the OP *does* want 2 columns in `xs` (or even in `sm`) viewport size, that this will still not work. Personally, I agree with only showing as a single row per-item on `xs` size; however I would beg to differ that it depends on the content/size of the "tile" as to how many columns to show (or not) when you're at an `xs`/`sm` size

Comment: @Vince Do u still want 2 columns in xs? if so you will need to add height to each column, and the height is going to be maximum column height so that they all float gracefully and in this case you will using a single .row class

Comment: Thank you @PavithraOlety. For the moment i have tried with the easiest - min-height.